# How do I permanently show softkeyboard on android

Tags: java, android, keyboard, show-hide, android-softkeyboard

I need my **softkeyboard** to be **always on**.
This line seems to do the thing on startup, but after i press enter and a value is checked, it still hides itself. 
I tried placing it again after the method is called, but it didn't help.

```
getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
```

Structure in shorted version:

```
//imports

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements TextWatcher{

//global variables


//stats
    public void stats() {
        //loading stats
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //on create stuff

        //never hide keyboard
        **getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);**

        //detecting enter
        editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                        // Enter has been pressed
                        takeTheGuess(v);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        stats();
    }

    public void takeTheGuess(View view) {
        //loading stats
        stats();
        //fixing blank field
        //checking for errors

        losowanie();

        stats();
    }

    public void losowanie() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        myNumber = rand.nextInt((100 - 0) + 1);
    }

    public void informacje(MenuItem item) {
       //app info
    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
         //safe type
         //no numbers bigger than 100
}
```

Comment: Why you need to show forever a keyboard? Users that uses it will hate you. I think is a concept problem,not a programming problem. Maybe it's impossible to show forever a keyboard with no choice of hide it when user wants.

Comment: Well i'm just testing sth
I want this part of an app to always have keyboard on, because the user will input the values repetitively.

Comment: Try to put the focus in the inputs to avoid the hidden of the keyboard, it's the only way **that I know** (maybe someone can help you), but I think that's a security feature of the O.S.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your activity's xml:

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
```

You can try to use one of these codes where you handle the enter key press:

```
InputMethodManager keyboard = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
keyboard.showSoftInput(v, 0);
```

If you get error in the variable v, try:

```
keyboard.showSoftInput((EditText)v, 0);
```

Another method:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
```

Another, this will request focus on your ediText to call the keyboard again:

```
v.requestFocus();
```